# How to stop browser loading localStorage Item when it's not available in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, auth0

Suppose I have a navbar which show a profile picture after login.
I'm using Auth0's lock, which set user profile in localStorage. The img-src came from localStorage.

NavbarView.html

```
 <li ng-if="!lgin.isAuthenticated"><a ng-click="lgin.authService.login()">Sign in</a></li>
 <li ng-if="lgin.isAuthenticated" class="dropdown">
     <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <strong>{{lgin.profile.name}}</strong>
     <img src="{{lgin.profile.picture}}" alt="{{lgin.profile.name}}">
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

loginController.js

```
 var lgin = this;
 lgin.isAuthenticated = $rootScope.isAuthenticated;
 var accessData = localStorage.getItem('profile');
 lgin.profile = angular.fromJson(accessData);
```

When user enter the homepage, the browser keep finding for lgin.profile.picture (which is not available, because they didn't login yet), so the spinner never stop unless logging in.
How to correct this?

Comment: doesn't this work ? `if(angular.isDefined(accessData)) { // your code }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple conditional. If a key doesn't exist, `getItem()` will return null

```
var accessData = localStorage.getItem('profile');
if(accessData ){
   lgin.profile = angular.fromJson(accessData);
}
```

Comment: note you should always use `ng-src` to avoid browser make bad requests for images. Really not sure what spinner you are talking about. Create a demo that reproduces issue

Comment: ng-src really corrected the problem. Thank you so much.